# SimpleXML : Add attributes to primitives

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I need to parse something like this

`<o:address>My address</o:address>`

that seems easy, but this element could come as follows

`<o:address p:nil="true" />`

How can I add a non-required attribute to a primitive, or in this case to a String object?

If there is no way, any suggestions of how could I handle this parsing?

I have no access to the model, I just receive the XML

Comment: the workaround was adding 'strict=false' to Root annotation, that way only parts I`m interested are parsed and no more exceptions for unexpected atttributes. I still do not know how to add attributes to primitives or String objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `required = false` in your annotations. To set an attribute optional, use

```
@Attribute(name = "nil", required = false)
```